# Stripe - Retrieving Billing / Shipping address from payer

Tags: javascript, c#, stripe-payments

I have this in my Javascript:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51Gv0ngD3zt5RrIg0XQiKHaK7TOAqzju9yps8jJB2Gch6ksmG4FSnqgyWLv3Qld2EkNHgAb30PLKduYGBuYtZe71A0066dp27DB');
var elements = stripe.elements();
// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
var style = {
    base: {
        // Add your base input styles here. For example:
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#32325d',
    },
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode: true, style: style });

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
    // which would refresh the page.
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: card,
        billing_details: {
            // Include any additional collected billing details.
            name: 'Jenny Rosen',
        },
    }).then(stripePaymentMethodHandler);
});

function stripePaymentMethodHandler(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Show error in payment form
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/PayStripe",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id,
            }),
            success: function (json) {
                handleServerResponse(json);
            }
        });
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(response) {
    if (response.error) {
        // Show error from server on payment form
    } else if (response.requires_action) {
        // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
        stripe.handleCardAction(
            response.payment_intent_client_secret
        ).then(handleStripeJsResult);
    } else {
        // Show success message

        window.location.href = "/Invoice";

    }
}

function handleStripeJsResult(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Show error in payment form
    } else {
        // The card action has been handled
        // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server

        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/PayStripeSave",
            data: JSON.stringify({ payment_intent_id: result.paymentIntent.id }),
            success: function (json) {
                handleServerResponse(json);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have this in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult PayStripe(string payment_method_id)
    {

        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_51Gv0ngD3zt5RrIg0KmTYo92QYmujb9Gp3dv8zz7fOJYjbLna3gRPOkHzZMSVMISHNgmPSrSncUtKL2DS86R4DEJI00mVv9GusU";
        var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
        PaymentIntent paymentIntent = null;

        using (var ctx = new maharaja_bpDBEntities())
        {

            

            try
            {
                var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
                {
                    PaymentMethod = payment_method_id,
                    Amount = 1099,
                    Currency = "gbp",
                    ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                    Confirm = true,
                };
                paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Create(options);
            }
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return Json(new { error = e.StripeError.Message });
            }
            return generatePaymentResponse(paymentIntent);


        }

    }
```

I looked in the paymentIntent object and found that the billing address and shipment are all null, but in my dashboard i have set the address details.

Can anyone help, how i can retrieve the billing and shipping address?

Or do i have to implement the Billing and Shipping address to be passed through to stripe?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what is being returned in response.  If the response doesn't contain the data than you have to modify the request.  I suspect the request headers needs to be modified (implement the Billing and Shipping address to be passed through to stripe).  The json .ajax is the request headers and must specify the data that gets returned in the response.

Comment: You're likely setting the details on the `Customer` in the dashboard, but looking at the `PaymentMethod` in your API response. Those are two different objects that are related but have different details. Once you [attach the PaymentMethod to a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach), you can see the relation on the objects and find the details from either by looking at the related object.